# Replace types on some keys in a Typescript type

Tags: typescript

In the following code, I am trying to create a new type from an existing type, by looping through the keys and replacing only the ones that match the condition.

I am also using union types here.

```js
class A {}

class B {
    constructor(public a: A, public n: number, public aa: A[]) {}
}

type X = A | B

type ReplaceKeyTypes<Type extends X, NewKeyType> = {
  [Key in keyof Type]: Key extends X ? NewKeyType : Type[Key]
}

const a: A = new A()
const b: B = new B(a, 1, [a, a])

const c: ReplaceKeyTypes<B, string> = {
    a: 'test',
    n: 2,
    aa: ['xyz']
}
```

This gives me the following errors in the last few lines of code:

- Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
- Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.

My questions are:

1. why does `c.n` get changed to a string, when the original key type is a number which does not satisfy "`Key extends X`"?
2. how can I also apply the change to keys who are an array of the union type? In this example, `c.aa` should change from `X[]` to `string[]`

Comment: I can take a closer look at this tomorrow, but “Key extends X“ doesn’t really make sense because you are comparing the key itself against a union of interfaces.  What is the actual condition where you are trying to replace?

Comment: Thanks Linda! I managed to find my error and posted an error below, but I'd be happy if you wanted to take a look at it and let me know if there's any improvements to make. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems when doing `Key in keyof Type` you get the literal key, i.e. the string that names the key. I had forgotten to get the key's **value** type by using `Type[Key]`. To fix, and to support the array case, here's what I came up with:

```js
type ReplaceKeyTypes<Type extends X, NewKeyType> = {
  [Key in keyof Type]: Type[Key] extends X[]
    ? NewKeyType[]
    : Type[Key] extends X
    ? NewKeyType
    : Type[Key]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this would work exactly as is with multiple keys you want to replace, but if you have just one key you want to "re-type" I've done:

```
type NewType = Omit<OldType, 'keyToChange'> & {
  keyToChange: NewTypeOfKey;
};
```

Haven't taken the time to genericize this but it would probably be pretty easy.

Answer (score -1):

```
type A = {
  a: string;
  b: string;
  c: string;
};

type B = Omit<A, "b" | "c">;

type C = Omit<A, "b" | "c"> & { b: number; c: number };
```

Now, if you **hover** over **`B`** you will see this:

```
type B = {
    a: string;
}
```

And type **`C`** has been this:

```
type C = {
  a: string;
  b: number; // Replaced
  c: number; // Replaced
};
```